# can't open pdf. error: File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported

Tags: 12.04, pdf

I am struggling to open an important pdf file I have on my ubuntu 12.04, which is probably created on MS Windows(assuming since it has some formatting issue). When I open the file using a PDF viewer it shows me this error: **File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported**

I tried to open it using terminal, too. Here is the output:

```
➜  pdf: gnome-open mypdf.pdf
Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error (30): Illegal character '{'
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table

➜  pdf:  evince my pdf.pdf    
Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error (30): Illegal character '{'
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Can anybody help me with solving this issue and to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't corrupted? What's the output of `pdfinfo <file>.pdf`?

Comment: I see these errors:


Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error (30): Illegal character '{'
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table

Comment: Being this file corrupted is my nightmare, and I think it's coming true. Just hoping for a way to get the content back. :(

Answer (score 3):

MIME type for a PDF on Ubuntu is `application/pdf`

but `application/octet-stream` (meaning any generic binary file) is a sort of catch all for files, and usually requires a file extension to determine what to open it with.

Download the PDF locally and save it as a PDF, making sure there is `.pdf` at the end.

Comment: I did try to change extension to `.pdf`, but it seems that there is no other way to get the data back. I think I'll have to live with accepting the fact that the file is corrupted. :(

Comment: And still no one know the solution for this annoying problems? it seems the corrupted or damaged pdf file can't be recovered

Comment: Maybe some of these methods? http://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file

Comment: I had one .pdf file which generated same message and others indicating - a corrupted file.  Unable to open it using LibreOffice components, **Google** browser, and file reader.  **Firefox** browser was able to open it and it turned out to be a scanned document.  Printed it using PDF output printing option.  The disadvantage with this is the PDF isn't searchable.